# ajax + php = живой поиск

Tags: ajax, php

Обгуглил весь веб, может кто сможет мне предложить свой или ранее использованый им живой поиск на сайт. В двух словах требования, вводитн в форму символы, php сценарий берет данные из mysql и передает браузеру... В общем должно выглядеть примерно так ))

[image: живой поиск]

Comment: Приметка, php сценарий напишу сам, а вот в аяксе и js я 0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<input type="text" id="search_box">
<div id="search_advice_wrapper">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#search_box').keyup(function(){
    if($(this).val().length>3){
      $.get('search_assistant.php',{'query':$(this).val()},function(data){
        data = eval('('+data+')');//json data. array of strings
        if(data.length!=undefined && data.length>0){
          $("#search_advice_wrapper").html('');
          for(i in data){
            $("#search_advice_wrapper").append('<div class="advice_variant">'+data[i]+'</div>');
          }
        }
      });
    }
  });

  $('.advice_variant').live('click',function(){
    $('#search_box').val($(this).text());
  });

</script>
```

Что-то типа того.

идея: при отпускании кнопки, скрипт читает аттрибут `"value"` текстового поля. Если он длиннее 3 символов, то отправляет эту строку в PHP обработчик, который по БД проверяет все возможные варианты для данного сочетания символов. Ну, например, `'like("'.$_GET['query'].'%")'` в Mysql. С этим вы сказали справитесь. Далее прилетает обратно массив строк, оформленный как Json(можно просто набор строчек, но теряется гибкость). Из этого массива каждая строка ложится в специальный блок search_advice_wrapper. При клике на строчку в этом блоке, ее содержимое отправляется в поле поиска.

Comment: Это jquery. И требует дополнительных библиотек.

Comment: из дополнительных библиотек тут только jquery. JSON можно ручками собрать. Для массива это очень просто.

Comment: ow... Прошу прощения. =) Заработался.

Answer (score 2):

[Вот статья](http://htmlweb.ru/ajax/example/search.php)

Answer (score 1):

Я бы еще советовал посмотреть sphinx.

Comment: Сфинкс ищет. А вопрос про вывод результатов поиска и промежуточных результатов

Comment: к чему было писать этот комент ?? что-то ответа я в нем не нахожу, только тролинг

Comment: @smail2133, вы кому?

Comment: вам, кому же еще.